# C# seralization in different thread

Tags: c#, serialization

I use the XmlSerializer of C# to save and load all models of my application to a file. Because these file operations can take some time, I want do this serialization/deserialization process in a different thread. To do this, I used a delegate and the "BeginInvoke" operation. 
The problem is that when all objects are deserialized that they are created by another thread and that all variables in these objects cannot be accessed by the GUI thread.

I know how to access an object from a different thread (by using the Dispatcher.invoke() method) but using this technique to access each variable is not an option in my application.

Is there a solution or easier way to serialize and deserialize objects in a different thread?

Edit:
When all objects are deserialized, the model notifies the view to create UI objects from the deserialized models.

```
    //In the Model:
    //when the deserialize operation is ready this handler is executed (not the GUI thread)
    void ProjectLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectLoadedEventArgs projectLoadedEventArgs = e as ProjectLoadedEventArgs;

        m_models = projectLoadedEventArgs.SerializedData.Models;

        Notify(null);
    }

    //In the view:
    public void Update(Object o)
    {
        model.Angle.... -> RIGHT VALUE!!!

        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
        {
            ResetCanvas();
             model.Angle... -> ERROR: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

        }));

    }
```

Comment: You probably got that backwards.  I can't think of a lot of classes that you could serialize that have thread affinity.  Surprise us all by actually naming these classes.

Comment: @Tom: what is an `EntityModel`? A plain data class? Does it have some functionality in that `Angle` property, apart from returning an angle?

Comment: Thanks for this comment I have found the problem!

These properties are dependencyProperties not basic properties....
Now Finding a solution for this or changing the dependencyproperties in normal properties if there is no other option....

Answer (score 1):

Deserializing thread has to store objects in some well known to UI thread place. Remember You will have to come up with some synchronization mechanism between threads.

I think I know why You have problems (I read comment to other answer). You deserialize and then notice UI that object is ready. You probably do sth like
`UIComponent.DeserializationFinished()`. In this method You modify the UI which is not allowed.

Comment: How do you mean? 
The deserialization process stores all objects in an object created by the UI thread... but variables of these objects cannot be accessed because the xmlserialization process was executed in another thread  and as a result all objects are created in this thead...

Comment: It doesn't matter what thread deserialized/created object. UI thread can access it. You just can't modify UI from thread different then UI thread. Please show some code.

Comment: When all objects are deserialized, the model notifies the view to create UI objects from the deserialized models.

        public void Update(Object o)
        {
            Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
            {
                ResetCanvas();

            }));
           
        }

Comment: Maybe try this just to see it works. Create static list that will hold deserialized objects and static flag that says it's in/after deserialization. In UI thread do while (flag_says it's not after deserialization) Thread.Sleep(100); And after while loop use Your model like You would like to use. That should work. Now modify code to have proper synchronization. Maybe use BackgroundWorker class.

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit]**

Since you've added the exception ("The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it") in the comment below, it's now clear that GUI controls are being accessed from a non GUI thread. [If you search for this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The%20calling%20thread%20cannot%20access%20this%20object%20because%20a%20different%20thread%20owns%20it), you will see that it's the **direct consequence** of refusing to use `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

I am afraid that you can do only two things:

1. **The preferred way:** Use `Dispatcher.Invoke` to invoke the async deserialization callback on a GUI thread (I realize you've said it's not an option, but it's actually the best way to do it). Remember that `Dispatcher.Invoke` doesn't access deserialized objects in any special way, it only invokes the callback handler on a GUI thread:

   ```
   // your async callback
   public void ObjectWasDeserialized(IAsyncResult result)
   {
       _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<IAsyncResult>(UpdateSomeControl), result);
   }
   ```
2. Don't use async callbacks at all, but a `Future` pattern as described below. But that forces you to poll the result from a GUI thread, which is a bad thing.

---

It doesn't matter what thread creates an object, its data is still accessible by other threads. What is **not** recommended is accessing GUI controls from a different thread.

What you probably need is a thread-safe way to signal the GUI thread that an object is ready to be accessed. That can be implemented as a `Future` object (as explained in [this article by Ayende](http://ayende.com/blog/3079/its-the-future-now)).

Your background thread should create a wrapper around your object, which also contains a `ManualResetEvent` set to false. After the object has been deserialized successfully, it should signal the event (`ManualResetEvent.Set()`). UI thread which wants to access the object will have to do it through a property which blocks on this same event until it's signaled. That's logical, since you cannot guarantee that the object will be ready anytime the GUI thread wishes it.

**[Edit]** Found the article with an implementation. First part is what I was talking about, and ends by defining the `InThe` class. The part which follows, however, is not necessary at all, and I don't recommend it.

Using the code provided by Ayende, you would have something like:

```
// a thread (it can even be a GUI thread) requests a future result
Future<SomeObject> future = InThe.Future<SomeObject>(() => Deserialize(file));

// later, in the GUI thread, you access the future wrapper directly
SomeObject result = future.Value; // this will block the calling thread until
                                  // result is ready
```

Comment: When the deserialization process is finished, the GUI is notified and the object is rendered so the objects in the model are ready at that time .... but they are created by another thread and as a result i get the following error each time I  access a member variable of such an object:

base {System.SystemException} = {"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."}

Comment: @Tom: The problem is not that these objects are **tied** to a thread, but GUI controls *are*. The problem is with the statement "the GUI is notified". In that moment, a non-GUI thread raises an event which causes the event handler to be executed by a background thread, and tries to access GUI controls to update them. This is what `Dispatcher.Invoke` does, it queues the event handler to the GUI thread. It doesn't change the way these objects are accessed.

Comment: @Tom: as you can see, your problem is a [pretty common one](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+calling+thread+cannot+access+this+object+because+a+different+thread+owns+it). It all boils down to ensuring that UI controls are not accessed by other threads.

Comment: Actually, in the update function in the GUI I use the Dispatcher.invoke() function.... I have added code to my original post.

Thanks for the comments, I hope I can fix this problem

Comment: I read your edited comment but as you can see from my edits in the orignial post i already used the dispatcher.invoke() method....

But when accessing a membervariable I get the error again...

Do I  need to use Dispatcher.invoke() each time when i want to access a membervar from the UI thread? this will cost me much time to change all this and what with bindings to the model in xaml....